# Mongodb: How to find TTL index are deleting Data from particular Days?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, ttl

How we can find out data is deleting from all collections after particular Days using TTL Index?

Answer (score 0):

Say your TTL is 10 days, you can do a count of the number of documents where the date is more than 10 days ago. To do such a count:

```
db.myCollection.count({"date":{"$lt":ISODate("2017-02-07T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

If TTL is working, you'd expect the count to be 0. Note that you need to give some extra time before deletion-by-TTL takes place. Deletion is not exactly at the specified moment because deletion is via a periodically-run background task.